# iFrame Showing up in Chrome, but not Safari/Firefox

Tags: wordpress, iframe, pardot

I am working to add a Pardot Form Handler Form into an Elementor HTML Snippet as an iFrame and while it is showing up fine in Chrome(default browser) , when I switch to Firefox or Safari, the form only shows the top two fields, and the only way to get to the next level of fields is to TAB through. I have tried to clear and delete the cache but to no avail.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pardot iFrame Resizing</title>
        <meta name="description" content="iFrame message passing test">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style type="text/css">
            iframe {
                border: 0;
                border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://go.hisshosushi.com/l/895511/2021-01-16/3fnc" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.2.11/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      iFrameResize({log:true});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem then I added a `z-index: 10;` and it showed up. No other z-index on the page.